# PHP: Why is `1<<63` negative and how can I change that?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

According to the title the code:

```
$a=<int> value;
$b=1<<$a;
echo "\n".$b."\n";
printf("%064b",$b);
$b=$b>>$a;
echo "\n".$b."\n";
printf("%064b",$b);
```

for value=62 prints (as expected):

```
4611686018427387904
0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 
1
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

but for value=63 (maximum, but no overflow) prints:

```
-9223372036854775808
1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
-1
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Can I do something to make `>>` the inverse of `<<` in the second case?

Comment: [Suggested Reading on "Two's Complement"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Ok thanks, got that. However, what I do is shifting bits. So my question is still: What is the general inverse of `<<`, to e.g. shift from `1000` to `0010`? Sure I can do k times `$b>>1 ^ $b`, but that's probably not equally efficient as `>>k` and only works for 1 bit, I guess.

Comment: `>>` is the inverse of `<<`, but when you change the most-significant bit of an integer, then it two's complements that value.... you can't change that without treating what you're shifting as something different to a signed integer

Comment: As far as I know there exists no unsigned integer in PHP. I was searching for that already.

Comment: `($b>>1 & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)>>($a-1)` ?

Comment: @AlexBlex I like! It's one extra step and I should however exclude 0 then, but that's ok I guess.